# Is it possible to use logarithms to convert numbers to binary?

Tags: binary, logarithm

I'm a CS freshman and I find the division way of finding a binary number to be a pain. Is it possible to use log to quickly find 24, for instance, in binary?

Comment: Logarithms apply to numbers - the base in which they are written is irrelevant (e.g. `log(1111b)` = `log(15)` = `log(0xF)`). Think about how you might convert an arbitrary number into decimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use logarithms, you **can**.

---

Define log<sub>2</sub>(*b*) as log(*b*) / log(2) or ln(*b*) / ln(2) (they are the same).

Repeat the following:

- Define *n* as the integer part of log<sub>2</sub>(b). There is a `1` in the *n*<sup>th</sup> position in the binary representation of *b*.
- Set *b* = *b* - 2<sup>n</sup>
- Repeat first step until *b* = 0.

---

**Worked example: Converting 2835 to binary**

- log<sub>2</sub>(2835) = 11.47.. => *n* = 11

  The binary representation has a 1 in the 2<sup>11</sup> position.
- 2835 - (2<sup>11</sup> = 2048) = 787

  log<sub>2</sub>(787) = 9.62... => *n* = 9

  The binary representation has a 1 in the 2<sup>9</sup> position.
- 787 - (2<sup>9</sup> = 512) = 275

  log<sub>2</sub>(275) = 8.10... => *n* = 8

  The binary representation has a 1 in the 2<sup>8</sup> position.
- 275 - (2<sup>8</sup> = 256) = 19

  log<sub>2</sub>(19) = 4.25... => *n* = 4

  The binary representation has a 1 in the 2<sup>4</sup> position.
- 19 - (2<sup>4</sup> = 16) = 3

  log<sub>2</sub>(3) = 1.58.. => *n* = 1

  The binary representation has a 1 in the 2<sup>1</sup> position.
- 3 - (2<sup>1</sup> = 2) = 1

  log<sub>2</sub>(1) = 0 => *n* = 0

  The binary representation has a 1 in the 2<sup>0</sup> position.

We know the binary representation has `1`s in the 2<sup>11</sup>, 2<sup>9</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, and 2<sup>0</sup> positions:

```
2^     11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
binary  1  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

so the binary representation of 2835 is `101100010011`.

Comment: I reread your question and saw you wanted 24 in binary. Using the same principle, you'd get 2^4 and 2^3, giving you 24 = `11000b`.

Comment: I started thinking about this today as a faster way to convert to binary. Found your answer very helpful. Glad to see I was on the right track.

Comment: well done, this is the best way that I know

Answer (score 1):

From a CS perspective, binary is quite easy because you usually only need to go up to 255. Or 15 if using HEX notation. The more you use it, the easier it gets.

How I do it on the fly, is by remembering all the 2 powers up to 128 and including 1. (The presence of the 1 instead of 1.4xxx possibly means that you can't use logs).

```
128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1
```

Then I use the rule that if the number is bigger than each power in descending order, that is a '1' and subtract it, else it's a '0'.

So 163

```
163 >= 128 = '1' R 35
35  !>= 64 = '0'
35  >= 32  = '1' R 3
3   !>= 16 = '0'
3   !>= 8  = '0'
3   !>= 4  = '0'
3   >=  2  = '1' R 1
1   >=  1  = '1' R 0

163 = 10100011.
```

It may not be the most elegant method, but when you just need to convert something ad-hoc thinking of it as comparison and subtraction may be easier than division.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to loop through 0 -> power which is bigger than you need and then take the remainder and do the same, which is a pain too.

I would suggest you trying recursion approach of division called 'Divide and Conquer'.

http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/lectures/05/Small05.pdf

But again, since you need a binary representation, I guess unless you use ready utils, division approach is the simplest one IMHO.